# replace value in a dataframe not working in a loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm running the following code to replace numbers by string (labels from a survey). The command line at the end of the code is working but when I try to create a loop the values are not replaced anymore.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a test data frame
df =pd.DataFrame([{'Q1_2':1,'Q1_3':4},{'Q1_2':1,'Q1_3':4},{'Q1_2':1,'Q1_3':4},{'Q1_2':1,'Q1_3':4}])

dfCategorical = {'Q1_2':'studylevel',
                'Q1_3':'studyfield'}

studylevel = {1:'Undergraduate (Bachelor level)',
              2:'Graduate (Master level)',
              3:'PhD',
              4:'Other (e.g., MBA)'}

studyfield = {1:'Arts / Humanities (e.g., cultural studies, history, linguistics, philosophy, religion)',
        2:'Business / Management',
        3:'Computer sciences / IT',
        4:'Economics',
        5:'Engineering (incl. architecture)',
        6:'uman medicine / health sciences',
        7:'Law',
        8:'Mathematics',
        9:'Natural sciences',
        10:'Science of art (e.g., art, design, dramatics, music)',
        11:'Social sciences (e.g., psychology, politics, education)',
        12:'Other'}

for key, value in dfCategorical.items():
    print(key,value)
    df.loc[:,key] = df.loc[:,key].replace(value)
```

But the values in df are not replaced. Thanks for helping me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this (or similar)...

**From:**

```
   Q1_2  Q1_3
0     1     4
1     1     4
2     1     4
3     1     4
```

**To:**

```
df.replace({'Q1_2': studylevel}).replace({'Q1_3': studyfield})

                             Q1_2       Q1_3
0  Undergraduate (Bachelor level)  Economics
1  Undergraduate (Bachelor level)  Economics
2  Undergraduate (Bachelor level)  Economics
3  Undergraduate (Bachelor level)  Economics
```

**Or...**

```
print(df.replace({'Q1_2': studyfield}).replace({'Q1_3': studyfield}))

                                                Q1_2       Q1_3
0  Arts / Humanities (e.g., cultural studies, his...  Economics
1  Arts / Humanities (e.g., cultural studies, his...  Economics
2  Arts / Humanities (e.g., cultural studies, his...  Economics
3  Arts / Humanities (e.g., cultural studies, his...  Economics
```

If so, and to keep the changes add `df =`  to the left of the commands to assign them back to the original dataframe.

Comment: You should be able to do it in one step with a single dictionary.

Comment: @mozway not sure what is being requested as there is no desired result included.

Comment: I'm trying to do this df.replace({'Q1_2': studylevel}).replace({'Q1_3': studyfield}) but would like to perform it in a loop.

Comment: @MDR I meant `df.replace({'Q1_2': studylevel, 'Q1_3': studyfield})`, independently of the data. No need to loop twice ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found it just via this simple way

```
dfCategorical = {'Q1_2':studylevel,
                'Q1_3':studyfield}
dfLabel = dfLabel.replace(dfCategorical)
```